# The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' in azure function and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, cors, azure-functions

Hi I am working in c# azure function and java-script. I have web page running locally and hitting azure function also in locally. Below is my azure function and it runs in

> negotiate: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/negotiate

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
    public static async Task<SignalRConnectionInfo> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req, IBinder binder,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        var data = await Authenticated(req, log);
        var connectionInfo = binder.Bind<SignalRConnectionInfo>(new SignalRConnectionInfoAttribute { HubName = "MapUpload", UserId = data });
        return connectionInfo;
    }
```

Then in local.settings.json I have configured

```
 "Host": {
    "CORS": "*"
  }
```

Below is my java-script code.

```
 <script>
   const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl('http://localhost:7071/api/')
   .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
   .build();

   connection.on('MapUpload', productOrdered);
   connection.onclose(() => console.log('disconnected'));

   console.log('connecting...');
   connection.start()
   .then(() => data.ready = true)
   .catch(console.error);
</script>
```

When I run run my javascript application I get below error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7071/api/negotiate' from origin 'http://localhost:3872' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have added  "CORS": "*" but still gives me above error. So May I know Is there configurations I am missing in the above code. Can someone help em to understand this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials), To use `credentials` with `cors` mode, You need to set

- `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true` and
- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should NOT be set to `*`

Translating to [local.settings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local),

```
 "Host": {
    "CORS": "http://localhost:3872",
    "CORSCredentials":true
  }
```

Comment: Just quick info In the above js codeI want to send jwt token. So how can i send? I tried something like this  const options = { "Authorization":"MyToken"} then  .withUrl('http://localhost:7071/api/', options) but token is not coming in azure function. Is that correct way I am sending?

Comment: @MrPerfect Kindly ask a new question. (That seems correct. You might wanna add "Bearer MyToken". Also documentation seems to suggest all localhost functions run anonymously. But am not a expert in azure, but cors)